# ActiveScaffold — When inserting a new record, how to enable entry fields for a column/model to which the being created model "belongs_to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activescaffold

I have the following database schema:

```
 create_table "addresses", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "road"
    t.string   "city"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "client_id"
  end

  create_table "clients", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "address_id"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "orders", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.integer  "client_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
end
```

and models:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :address
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

The intention of this setup is to have records of many Clients, each Client has an address. Multiple clients can have the same address. The client_id in the addresses table is used for this purpose.

When I visit the /Clients ActiveScaffold view, and click create I am able to enter data for the new client, including the data of the new address for the client.

But, when I visit the /Orders view and click create, I can add a new Client and enter the data for him, but for the address there is only a select box, which only can be used to select an existing address, there are no fields to create a new address for the new client.
How can I include the address fields for the new client, in order to create a new address for the client?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not really push ActiveScaffold that far, but the associations on your tables look a little strange - you have a foreign key on both sides of the relationship, that is:

> *addresses* has a **client_id**

and

> *clients* has an **address_id**

I'd have thought only one side of that is strictly needed, eg **client_id** on *addresses*.

Possibly related, but you have belongs_to on either side of the relationship - perhaps one side should be a [has_one](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association) relationship, that is:

```
class Client
  has_one :address
end

class Address
  belongs_to :client
end
```

Hope that helps, Chris.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but actually I have written my own forms contollers for this purpose etc, I am not using ActiveScaffold for this project anymore.

Comment: @denysonique - no worries, useful to know.  I have been rails_admin for rails3 these days and like you say, its just a stopgap until we get round to writing it properly for the app :)